# Combinatorics - Recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

For each positive integer $n$, let $a_{n}$ be the number of binary sequences of length $n$ which do not contain the sub-sequence '011'. Find a recurrence relation for $a_{n}$ and determine the initial condition.

$a_{1}$ = 2

$a_{2}$ = 4

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=$ number of strings that starts with '$00$'.

$b_n=$ number of strings that starts with '$01$'.

$c_n=$ number of strings that starts with '$10$'.

$d_n=$ number of strings that starts with '$11$'.
$$\\$$
Then,

$a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$ (attach '$0$' in front of $a_n$ or $b_n$).

$b_{n+1}=c_n$ (attach '$0$' in front of $c_n$ [but not $d_n$]).

$c_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$ (attach '$1$' in front of $a_n$ or $b_n$).

$d_{n+1}=c_n+d_n$ (attach '$1$' in front of $c_n$ or $d_n$).

$s_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+c_{n+1}+d_{n+1}=2\cdot s_n - d_n$.

Comment: $d_{n+2}=c_{n+1}+d_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n=s_n$